# Looping though file to extract lines

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io

I am very new to python. I am trying to extract specific lines skipping the header lines which repeats in periodic interval in a text file and write them down in another file. I have been able to do this with the following code but this is extremely slow.

```
import random
import sys
import os

with open('test.txt', encoding ='latin1') as rf: 
    with open('test1.txt', 'w') as wf:
        for x, line in enumerate(rf): #reads the line number
            #nskip = 3 #number of headers to skip
            #nloop = 5 #number of loops in the file
            ndata = 7 #number of lines in each loop
            data = 4 #number of lines to be extracted 
            x+=1
            #print(x,line)

            for i in range(1,ndata+1):
                for j in range((ndata*i - data)+1, ndata*i+1):
                    if x == j:
                        #print(line)
                        wf.write(line)
```

eg. from this code I able to get Line5,Line6,Line7,Line12,Line13,Line14,Line19,Line20,Line21 (if you think test file has lines like Line1, Line2, Line3, so on for each line) so on which I intend. But the problem is my real file is way bigger and it take a lot of time and memory. There must be a more faster and pythonic way of doing this.

Also I like to be able to add loop number in lines in each loop i.e. 1st loop would get 1 in all the lines (somewhere in each line, may be Line5 1, Line6 1, Line7 1, Line12 2, Line13 2, Line14 2, Line19 3 so on). Though what I am trying to do is somewhat complicated than this. But this should pave my way through. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the headers and records come in fixed sizes, skip the number header lines and write the number of record lines repeatedly until the end of the file is reached.

```
n_header_lines = 25
n_record_lines = 100
page_num = 0

with open('test.txt', encoding ='latin1') as rf, with open('test1.txt', 'w') as wf:
    try:
        while True:
            page_num += 1
            for _ in range(n_header_lines):
                next(rf)
            for line_num in range(1, n_record_lines + 1):
                prefix = 'Line {:3d} {:3d} '.format(line_num, page_num)
                wf.write(prefix + next(rf)))
    except StopIteration:
        pass
```

Comment: Tried this on the test file with n_header_lines = 4 and n_record_lines = 3. With 7 lines in each loop: The out put was line 5, 7, 9, 15, 17, 19, 25, 27, 29 and so on...I would expect to be line 5,6,7,12,13,14,19,20,21 so on. So the code is not that helpful. Any more suggestions? Thanks for the post.

Comment: @Luck4u: This skipping of every other line would indicate that you are iterating over `rf` outside of the calls to `next(rf)`. Make sure that you don't have any code like `for line in rf:`. Also remember that each call to `next(rf)` consumes one line. If you do that twice inside a for-loop it will consume at twice the anticipated rate. What I'm trying to say is the concept is sound, your implementation of it is lacking. Add it to your question if you want me to look it over.

Comment: Just edited the question. Hope it makes more sense now. Thanks!

Comment: @Luck4u:  Edited to include line numbering and page numbering.

Comment: Thank you are the life saver:)